# How to create 4 rows in one column cell in sharepoint list to separately mention details within one column cells

Tags: sharepoint

I need to mention details in sharepoint list under one row but in some columns cells need to be seperated into sub-row to mention sub details seperately just like unmerge cell.

I want to make it as below image. Hope your support

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOy1Y.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if SharePoint handles this type of request or if it does I have never run across it. See ([How to create sub-lists in sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645378/how-to-create-sub-lists-in-sharepoint))

My suggestion would be to create a list with all of those columns stacked horizontally and none of them nested.  (Name, Contact, Email, Supplier, Address,City, Lane, Village)  On the form itself I would let people enter in the information and pass that back to the list itself with the Address column concatenating itself from the City, Lane and Village inputs